# Confused over C++ Stack Usage

Tags: c++, nodes, stack

I'm new to this website and will try to contribute just as much as I ask. Also, please know I never ask a question without spending much time trying to figure it out myself.

As such, C++ Stacks are driving me f***ing crazy.

My Question: where do I place my variables/values in the Stack function block to actually use it. I understand Stacks are a LIFO data-structure, I've read countless examples of stacking plates on top of each other, etc.

**Look at this code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 100;

class StackOverFlowException 
{
    public:
        StackOverFlowException() 
        {
            cout << "Stack overflow" << endl;
        }
};

class StackUnderFlowException 
{
    public:
        StackUnderFlowException() 
        {
            cout << "Stack underflow" << endl;
        }
};

class ArrayStack 
{    
    private:        
        int data[MAX_SIZE];        
        int top;    
  public:        
      ArrayStack() 
      {            
          top = -1;        
    }        

    void Push(int element)
    {            
        if ( top >= MAX_SIZE ) 
            {            
                throw new StackOverFlowException();
            }                   
            data[++top] = element;        
    }        

    int Pop()
    {            
        if ( top == -1 ) 
            {            
                throw new StackUnderFlowException();            
            }            
            return data[top--];        
    }        

    int Top() 
    {            
        return data[top];        
    }

    int Size() 
    {
        return top + 1;
    }

    bool isEmpty() 
    {
        return ( top == -1 ) ? true : false;
    }
};
```

[etc....]

It's basic cookie-cutter....*let's say I'm trying to adapt it to express a system where the last food orders placed in, are kicked out first; variables are 'food', 'orders', and whatever else.
Where in the world am I integrating those variables into that stack code above!?!??!*

Please help so confused i'm about to indiscriminately punch something

Comment: That would be a terrible restaurant.

Comment: Basically you want to "push" you orders on the stack, then "pop" them.

Comment: First person to order waits forever...

Comment: what about `std::stack`? If you really want the over/underflows, just wrap it and add a counter at pop/push, no need at all to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @KilianDS: talking about the wheel, std::stack has it's own counter (`size`) (not to mention what happens if you pass a container to the constructor...)

Comment: The more I look into it, the more it looks like a homework assignment. There is no way a person competent enough to write the basic C++ stack code would not know what to do next to use it for his data. Probably the question is part of a homework assignment, and the boilerplate code is from the interwebs or the class book.

Answer (score 4):

A stack implementation could use templates so that you could put whatever you want in the stack (within reason).

For example, have a class that encapsulates all the data related to orders (this one is just an example):

```
class FoodOrder
{
    int orderNumber;
    time_t orderTime;

    // add more variables here
}
```

Then, your stack could look like this:

```
template<typename T> class Stack
{
    T data[MAX_SIZE];
    int top;

    void Push(T item);
    T Pop(void);

    // add methods
}
```

Then, you could have a `Stack` of whatever items you want:

```
Stack<int> stackOfInts;
Stack<std::string> stackOfStrings;
Stack<FoodOrder> stackOfOrders;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the existing `std::stack` and wrap it if you want the exceptions, for example like this (note you could easily templatize it):

```
class protectedstack
{
private:
    std::stack<int> stack;
    const int myarbitraryupperlimit = 100;
public:
    void pop() 
    {
        if(stack.empty()) 
        {
            throw new StackUnderFlowException();            
        }
        stack.pop();
    }
    void push(const int& value)
    {
        if(stack.size()>=myarbitraryupperlimit)
        {
            throw new StackOverFlowException();
        }
        stack.push(value);
    }
    // Similar for top/empty/constructors/...
};
```

Comment: @MooingDuck: then it should be specified as such

Answer (score 1):

The type of data, as well as that of what Top & Pop return, and what Push takes as an argument, is what is contained in the stack; that's what you'd replace w/ the type of whatever you want to make this a stack of.

Answer (score 1):

This is a stack:

[image: stack]

Think of it this way: the only way to add a book without moving the others is to place it on top : this is what `Push` does. So by calling `Push(Book1)`, you'd be placing Book1 on top of the pile.

Similarly, the only way to take away a book  without moving the others is to take the one on top : this is what `Pop` does. So by calling `Pop()`, you'd be getting (and removing from the stack) whichever book is on top of the stack, which in the image is the green book.

Am I missing something or was this your question?

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the `top` variable. This variable dictates which object is the current top. When you `pop()`, then the `top` variable is reduced- meaning that the top is now one below where it was. When you `push()`, it's incremented- the top is now one above where it was. This variable is what accounts for the LIFO functionality of the stack.

You can, of course, `template` the class to make it work with a `FoodOrder` or whatever.

Comment: Just the current stack index is at the "top". The actual data/values (for which he is asking) are in the "data" array. He already has the "top" thing nailed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the confusion. The data would go in, duh!, the "data" variable.

So, you either use Templates, to make the data buffer able to hold anything, or you change the type of the data to what you specifically need.

If for example you have a FoodOrder class, you can do it like this (my C++ is rusty, but this is basically the gist of it):

FoodOrder *data[MAX_SIZE];

You would have to change the push/pop parameters to accept a FoodOrder pointer/reference accordingly, and you're set.

P.S. About using std::stack --this might be a better solution, but doesn't answer his specific question.

P.S 2 Poster writes: "I'm new to this website and will try to contribute just as much as I ask.". Really? So why hasn't he even picked an answer yet? Does this smell more like a homework assignment?